# Run Batch Command Without Checking For Confirmation

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that restarts several computers in my center.  The batch file works fine but I would like if it ran faster. The reason it is slow is when it runs into a computer that has been turned off, it continues to try to find that computer for about 15 seconds before it moves to the next one.

Can I lower the time a batch command looks for the computer or just have it send the command and move on to the next?

I have pasted my current batch command below:

```
shutdown /f /r /m \\VAMAR-3STHWV1 /t 000
```

Comment: Try doing `ping` to the computer before running the `shutdown` command.

Comment: Us the START command with the shutdown command. `start "" shutdown /f /r /m \\VAMAR-3STHWV1 /t 000`

Comment: I like the ping idea.  What kind of response can I expect from the START command?  This sounds like it would add more delay.

Comment: @DavidRichards, how did you come to that conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `ping` command I believe you can do it. By telling the `ping` command to only send one echo request and then `&&`ing the result with the `shutdown` command, something like:

```
 ping VAMAR-3STHWV1 -n 1 >nul && shutdown /f /r /m \\VAMAR-3STHWV1 /t 000
```

That way the `shutdown` command gets executed only when the `ping` successfully reached out `VAMAR-3STHWV1` in one echo request.